# Android save and restore TextView text ViewPager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my `ViewPager` i have some fragments which i change some `TextView` texts dynamically, after switch between pages texts of `TextView`s clear, and i can't save and restore them from `instance`

this is my code and dont work

```
private       String                       value1;
private       String                       value2;
private       String                       value3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //@formatter:off
        context            = getActivity().getBaseContext();
        activity           = getActivity();
    //@formatter:on
}
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle inState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(inState);
    if (inState != null) {
        inState.getString("value1", value1);
        inState.getString("value2", value2);
        inState.getString("value3", value3);

        sahmiyeh_value_1.setText(value1);
        sahmiyeh_value_2.setText(value2);
        sahmiyeh_value_3.setText(value3);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@Nullable Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("value1", sahmiyeh_value_1.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("value2", sahmiyeh_value_2.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("value3", sahmiyeh_value_3.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `freezesText`

```
<TextView 
 ... 
 android:freezesText="true" />
```

From documentation :

> If set, the text view will include its current complete text inside of its frozen icicle in addition to meta-data such as the current cursor position. By default this is disabled; it can be useful when the contents of a text view is not stored in a persistent place such as a content provider

Comment: @LaraBelle Owl eye :)

Comment: @Piyush because I am confused about the freezesText. I'm still new to android. So, I tried to find article and found out the he just copied Raghav Sood answer.

Comment: @LaraBelle Its good thing for development ! I hope you would be gone a good developer !

Answer (score 2):

You didn't declare the string value.

`value1, value2, value3` is empty. That's why there's no value on your TextView or EditText.

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle inState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(inState);
    if (inState != null) {
        value1 = inState.getString("value1");
        value2 = inState.getString("value2");
        value3 = inState.getString("value3");

        sahmiyeh_value_1.setText(value1);
        sahmiyeh_value_2.setText(value2);
        sahmiyeh_value_3.setText(value3);
    }
}
```

Or you can do it like this.

```
sahmiyeh_value_1.setText(inState.getString("value1"));
sahmiyeh_value_2.setText(inState.getString("value2"));
sahmiyeh_value_3.setText(inState.getString("value3"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much miss :)

Comment: Welcome :) I'm glad (atleast) I helped you.